# If there are multiple expenses in a project, how can I sum them together and make a single row?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

[I have two table as you can see that relations each other.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buKV3.png)

[I want to see this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Hy3z.png)

How to do that in my blade file or controller.

this is my blade file;

```
@foreach ($costs as $cost)
                    @foreach ($projects as $project)
                    @if($project->id == $cost->project_id)


                  <tr class="odd">
                    <td>{{ $project->id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $cost->price }}</td>

                  </tr>

                  @endif
                  @endforeach
                  @endforeach



public function tablo1()
    {
        $costs =  DB::table('cost_manages')
            ->whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('projects')
                    ->whereColumn('projects.id', 'cost_manages.project_id')->groupBy('project_id');
            })
            ->get();

        $projects =  DB::table('projects')
            ->whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('cost_manages')
                    ->whereColumn('cost_manages.project_id', 'projects.id');
            })
            ->get();

        

        return view('home.muhasebe_Tablo1', [
            'costs' => $costs,
            'projects' => $projects
        ]);
    }
```

That one is my controller.
There are 2 costs for project number 11. I want to write a single record by collecting them.
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use join:

```
DB::table('projects')
->leftjoin('cost_manages', 'projects.id','const_manages.project_id')
->select('projects.id as id', 'projects.name as name', 'cost_manages.cost as cost')->get()
```

and then loop through this.

Comment: I want to sum up the columns of records number 11 and write them as a single record. I think you did not understand me.

Comment: you are right. try this:

`
DB::table('projects')
->leftjoin('cost_manages', 'projects.id','const_manages.project_id')
->select('projects.id', DB::raw(sum('cost_manages.cost'))
->groupBy('projects.id')
->get()
`

Comment: thanks it worked! What should I do if I want to pull my project name from another related table?   Project : Id, work_id (for project name) | Work : Id, name

Comment: you can do it by one more join in your query:
`DB::table('projects')
->leftjoin('works', 'works.id','projects.work_id')
 ->leftjoin('cost_manages', 'projects.id','const_manages.project_id')
->select('projects.id', 'works.name', DB::raw(sum('cost_manages.cost'))
->groupBy('projects.id', 'works.name')
->get()`.
I wish I understand what you want

Comment: It worked again. Thank you so much! 
So can i fetch data from other related table inside this query? for example the user_id in the event table and the salary of that user?  Tables : Project , Event , User --> Event : Id | user_id | project_id  , User : Id | Name | Salary . I want to see this ; "Project Id" "User Id" "Event Id" "User Salary" -->for example ; Project 1          User1        Event1      40$

Comment: yes, you can merge tables as much as you want

Comment: How to do this can you give an example? ->leftjoin('cost_manages', 'projects.id', 'cost_manages.project_id') I can not write this line for project and user. Because they do not have foreign key. Shoul I write ---> DB::table('users') <--- for fetching user salary to Project table?